# Can i nest to one off two parents with LESS

Tags: css, input, nested, textarea, less

I have this LESS set up. I'm wondering, is there any option to nest for one of two parents?

```
 input[type="text"].text_field,
 textarea.text_field {
    // style for both

    textarea + & {
      // style for only text area
    }
  }
```

I need to add some other style for `textarea` and i do not want to take it beyond the main rule. So, is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try something like this if you want to keep them in the same rule:

```
.text_field {
  color: black;

  input& {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  textarea& {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, everywhere I check this solution is recommended but when i do this nest isn't working...

Comment: ok i know why, that's bc i have this rule in body tag, is there any option to ignore body tag?

Comment: Not that I know of. Any reason you are nesting inside the body tag? Seems a bit deep to nest IMO. You could probably make it more generic and move it outside of the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
 input[type="text"].text_field, textarea.text_field {
    // style for both
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
 }
 textarea.text_field {
    // style for only text area, you can use !important if you want to use different style, and you used it in input[type="text"].text_field, textarea.text_field
    font-size: 13px !impotrant;
 }
```

nest example:

```
 ul {
   // style
   li {
     // style
     a:link, a:hover, a:visited {
       // style: color, font-size, etc.
     }
     a:hover {
       text-decoration: underline;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: It would seem that this answer does not meet the qualification to "not ... take it beyond the main rule," as you have taken the `textarea` out of the main rule (which is obviously _a_ solution, but not one that meets the criteria the OP set).

Comment: sorry but this is obviously solution and is not related to my question